# How do I get the day name in Excel to work in a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I converted the date using custom and the type is dddd.That worked fine, but when I reference the cell that the converted date is in using the countif function it won't calculate. I thought there was a problem with my formula but when I manually enter the day my formula worked.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you may have just formatted the appearance of the value instead of converting it.  You will need to provide details of your formulas and values for people to be able to know exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the date use 'Text' function as:

```
=TEXT(A1,"dddd")
```

this should solve your problem.